# Watch route object in VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, watch

How to watch route object on VueJS 2?. This is my code

```js
watch: { 
  '$route.params.search': function(search) {
    console.log(search)
  }
}
```

It doesn't work.

I try use with deep still not working on [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/xvx81l9wrw)

Look on code sandbox you can watch route object on main.js.

> You should not watch for the route object inside any other components. Because components get destroyed when router link changes. You should do it in the main.js file, according to your directory structure

Thanks @santanu and @ittus

Comment: I think it might be counter-productive to use `vue` to watch `vue-router`, especially when `vue-router` has built in hooks for this exact reason

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Did you try `deep` option?

```js
watch: { 
  '$route.params.search': {
    handler: function(search) {
      console.log(search)
    },
    deep: true,
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: On this case i change params with router link from other component.

Comment: Does it work if you only watch $route? ```watch: { 
     '$route': {
        handler: function(to) {
           console.log(to.params)
        },
        deep: true
      }
}```

Comment: I make a simple exmaple on here can you look [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/xvx81l9wrw)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? To have `params`, you need to pass parameter to router like [document](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html). Otherwise, `$route.params` is empty object.

Comment: I am already to pass params with ```methods: {
    goTo: function(page) {
      this.$router.push({ name: page, params: { page: page } });
    }
  }```

I look params is not empty on my devtools

Comment: This for result params is not empty object you can look on my codesanbox.

Comment: Ok, I see. So you can watch your `$route.params` now. You might want to add `immediate: true` option on watcher. I updated my answer.

Comment: Quick tip. In vue 3 deep:true is not required. Remembering that this tag brings bad performance

Answer (score 34):

In my code i did like the following -

```js
watch:{
  '$route' (to, from){
    // Put your logic here...
  }
},
```

Don't watch for the **$route** object inside any other components. Because as the router link changes the component gets destroyed and new component is being mounted. So the watchers for the component gets destroyed.
Watch for the **$route** object inside the root Vue instance where you inject the **router** object. like the following --

```js
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from){
      // Code
    }
  }
}).$mount('#element');
```

Comment: Hay @santanu i following your code still not work. Can you help me on [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvx81l9wrw)

Comment: You should not watch for the route object inside any other components. Because components get destroyed when router link changes. You should do it in the main.js file, according to your directory structure.

Comment: @santanubera if said component never gets destroyed then it's totally valid to watch the route object from it, for example your navigation component.

Answer (score 14):

Simple use:

```js
watch: {
    "$route.params.search"(value) {
      //Your code here
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

I was having trouble with reactivity, dynamically changing route with a router-link.

The issue was that the route will change but my siteData fetched from a method returned by data() was not:

I had to watch the route like so:

```
    watch: {
      '$route' (to, from) {
        if(to !== from ) {
          this.siteData = this.getSiteData();
        }
      }
    },
```

Hope this helps others with this problem